# vue.js - recursive components doesn't get updated when using nested array from raw json

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, vue.js

I am trying to create a tree with an add function using computed data. I used the tree-view example in vuejs official homepage and combined it with the computed function that I created but found no luck in implementing it. I've been trying to solve this for 4 days already and still no luck so I am here looking for help.

When you click the "+" in the end of the list it will trigger a call to the `addChild` function and it will successfully append the data. The data gets appended but the recursive component is not reactive.

https://jsfiddle.net/znedj1ao/9/

```js
var data2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name":"games",
    "parentid": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "movies",
    "parentid": null
  },
  {
   "name": "iron-man",
    "id": 3,
    "parentid": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "iron-woman",
    "parentid": 3
  }
]

// define the item component
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    model: Object
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function () {
      return this.model.children &&
        this.model.children.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
      }
    },
    changeType: function () {
      if (!this.isFolder) {
        Vue.set(this.model, 'children', [])
        this.addChild()
        this.open = true
      }
    },
    addChild: function () {
       this.model.children.push({
        name: 'My Tres',
     children: [
       { name: 'hello' },
       { name: 'wat' }
        ]
      })

    }
  }
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    treeData2: data2
  },
  computed: {
   nestedInformation: function () {     
            var a= this.nestInformation(data2);
            return a;
        }
  
  },
  methods:
    {
        nestInformation: function(arr, parent){  
           var out = []
    for(var i in arr) {
        if(arr[i].parentid == parent) {
            var children = this.nestInformation(arr, arr[i].id)

            if(children.length) {
                arr[i].children = children
            }
            out.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return out
    }
    }
})
```

```html
<!-- item template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <div
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      @click="toggle"
      @dblclick="changeType">
      {{model.name}}
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{open ? '-' : '+'}}]</span>
    </div>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item
        class="item"
        v-for="model in model.children"
        :model="model">
      </item>
      <li class="add" @click="addChild">+</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

<p>(You can double click on an item to turn it into a folder.)</p>

<!-- the demo root element -->
<ul id="demo">
  <item
    class="item"
    :model="nestedInformation[1]">
  </item>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not a Vue expert but adding elements to an array using push doesn't make the added properties reactive i guess. You might wanna try `$set` or `Vue.set()`. But i am really not sure.

Comment: I already tried that it doesn't work. It should work you can check it here ,https://jsfiddle.net/3p0j5sgy/1368/ , the only difference is I am passing a data that is already in parent-child structure.

Comment: my problem is my data is raw and I need to convert it first to tree structure before passing.

Comment: You might also want to read [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: I have already read and tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vue.js documentation that [Abdullah Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094731/abdullah-khan) [linked](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats) to in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961578/vue-js-recursive-components-doesnt-get-updated-when-using-nested-array-from-r#comment82892689_47961578) above says:

> Again due to limitations of modern JavaScript, **Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion**.

However, property addition is *exactly* what you are doing in your `nestInformation` method:

```
if(children.length) {
    arr[i].children = children
}
```

The result is that the `children` property of each object is *not* reactive, so when this Array is pushed to in `addChild`, no re-render is triggered in the UI.

The solution will be to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set-target-key-value) when creating the `children` Arrays so that they will be reactive properties. The relevant code in the `nestInformation` method must be updated to the following:

```
if (children.length) {
    Vue.set(arr[i], 'children', children);
}
```

I have forked and modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/hr8dhy8n/) for reference.