# vue js recursively flatten nested parent-children object

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js

I am trying to flatten the following data , but apparently my recursive function in vue method is not working properly. While I was debugging I noticed that once It enters the reduce function the 'this' variable change into something else(originally vue component).

```
{
  "id":1,
  "level":"1",
  "text":"Sammy",
  "type":"Item",
  "children":[
     {
        "id":11,
        "level":"2",
        "text":"Table",
        "type":"Item",
        "children":[
           {
              "id":111,
              "level":"3",
              "text":"Dog",
              "type":"Item",
              "children":null
           },
           {
              "id":112,
              "level":"3",
              "text":"Cat",
              "type":"Item",
              "children":null
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "id":12,
        "level":"2",
        "text":"Chair",
        "type":"Item",
        "children":[
           {
              "id":121,
              "level":"3",
              "text":"Dog",
              "type":"Item",
              "children":null
           },
           {
              "id":122,
              "level":"3",
              "text":"Cat",
              "type":"Item",
              "children":null
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
 }
```

desired result

```
 {
   "id":1,
   "level":"1",
   "text":"Sammy",
   "type":"Item",
   "children":[]
 }
 {
   "id":11,
   "level":"2",
   "text":"Table",
   "type":"Item",
   "children":[]
 }
 ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hr8dhy8n/11/ here is my repo.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/47961578/3397771
var data =[
   {
      "id":1,
      "level":"1",
      "text":"Sammy",
      "type":"Item",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":11,
            "level":"2",
            "text":"Table",
            "type":"Item",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":111,
                  "level":"3",
                  "text":"Dog",
                  "type":"Item",
                  "children":null
               },
               {
                  "id":112,
                  "level":"3",
                  "text":"Cat",
                  "type":"Item",
                  "children":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":12,
            "level":"2",
            "text":"Chair",
            "type":"Item",
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":121,
                  "level":"3",
                  "text":"Dog",
                  "type":"Item",
                  "children":null
               },
               {
                  "id":122,
                  "level":"3",
                  "text":"Cat",
                  "type":"Item",
                  "children":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]


// define the item component
Vue.component('item', {
  methods: {
flattenInformation: function(a, b) {
            return a.reduce(function (p, c) {
            !!c.children ? (p.push(c), this.flattenInformation(c.children, p), c.children = []) : p.push(c);return p;
         }, b);
        },
        getLengthNow (model) {
        var list = [];
        list.push(model);
        var flatten = this.flattenInformation(list,[]);
        
    }
  },
  props: ['model'],
  template: '#item-template'
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  data: {
    nestedData: data
  },
  el: '#demo'
});
```

```html
<!-- item template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
<template>
{{this.getLengthNow(this.model)}}
</template>
</script>

<!-- the demo root element -->
<ul id="demo">
  <item
    class="item"
    :model="nestedData[0]">
  </item>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions instead of `function` keyword, to keep `this` from your Vue. instance scope. `Function` creates it's own scope thus you lose access to outer `this` :-)

```
Vue.component('item', {
  methods: {
flattenInformation: (a, b) => {
            return a.reduce((p, c) => {
            !!c.children ? (p.push(c), this.flattenInformation(c.children, p), c.children = []) : p.push(c);return p;
         }, b));
        },
        getLengthNow (model) {
        var list = [];
        list.push(model);
        var flatten = this.flattenInformation(list,[]);

    }
  },
  props: ['model'],
  template: '#item-template'
})
```